# Rich text edior and syntax highlighter in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to develop a application like forum in ruby on rails.

Features:

- Forum with all categories.
- Rich text editor like stackoverflow.com editor.
- Syntax highlight  is important feature.

Please any one suggest good gems for my requirement.

Comment: try with this gem [forum_monster](https://github.com/codezomb/forum_monster)

Comment: Hi Gagan thanks for your reply. I have seen there is no text editor in that gem, for that I can integrate CK-Editor. There is no Syntax highlight feature in CK-editor also.

Comment: for syntax highlight feature you can see this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/207-syntax-highlighting) and use this [GEM](https://github.com/simplabs/highlight)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Redcarpet](http://railscasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet?view=comments). Here's a 7 minute rails cast showing specifically how to set it up and customize the options in your editor. It seems like what you're looking for and is very simple.